# How to put a textview-listview-textview after a textview-listview-textview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Please help me how to achieve something like this programmatically.

TextView
ListView
TextView

TextView
ListView
TextView

Here is layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gsy"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rsegtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RateSegmentname"/> 

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    </ListView>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total"/> 

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code where i can add a details to the listview

```
  for(a = 1; a < ratesegcode; a++){

     ArrayList<ClassForComputation> listcomputation = new ArrayList<ClassForComputation>(); 

        double sum = 0;
        double gamount = 0;

        String query = "SELECT rcomponent, amnt, gamount FROM computation WHERE ratesegmentcode =\""+a+"\" ORDER BY ratesegmentcode, printorder";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

           if(c != null && c.getCount() != 0){  
                c.moveToFirst();
           do{

              TextView rsegtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rsegtitle);
              rsegtitle.setText(GetRateSegment(a));                     
              ClassForComputation clsfrcomp = new ClassForComputation();         
              clsfrcomp.setratecomponent(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("rcomponent")));              
              clsfrcomp.setamount(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("amnt")));            
              gamount = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("gamount"));            
              clsfrcomp.setgrossamount(gamount); 

              sum = sum + gamount;

              listcomputation.add(clsfrcomp);

           }while(c.moveToNext());

           PowerUtilityAdapter powerListAdapter = new PowerUtilityAdapter(this, listcomputation);

           lv.setAdapter(powerListAdapter);
           }

           TextView total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
           String totl = Double.toString(sum);
           total.setText(totl);

        c.close();  
    }
```

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

You can display the lists views by setting up the adapters to both the list view, But two list view on a screen is not a good idea from a user point of view, instead use a two linearlayout which has a textview for a header, just load the list to the layout on user click over the linearlayout and unload or gone the other.

To set the adapter to a list view simply use:

```
ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

create a adapter class by extends `ArrayAdapter<Object>` or `SimpleArrayAdapter` according to your need.